# how to filter result from azure graph API using oData query

Tags: c#, json, odata, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to filter the result from graph api. i have 20 users. i want to make wild card search with user name starts with 's', so all the username will come from 's'.For this i am trying the odata query

```
signInNames/any(x:x/ startswith(value,'s'))
```

so i am looking all the username, name start with s. below is graph function.

```
var JSON2 = await SendGraphRequest("/users/", $"$filter=signInNames/any(x:x/ startswith(value,'r'))", null, HttpMethod.Get);
```

[I have also attached json data screenshot, from i have to filter the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlJnI.jpg)

TIA

Answer (score 1):

While using /users API to filter users via signInNames , only equals-match is supported in ODATA Query expression.
For example:

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?$filter=signInNames/any(c:c/value eq '***')
```

If you try to filter users via startswith , you will get error as below:
URL:

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?$filter=signInNames/any(c:startswith(c/value, 'm'))
```

Method:
GET

```
Response:
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "value only supports equals-match. PrefixMatch is not supported."
        },
        "requestId": "aa3f1c9a-abec-425b-b187-a669a6d69cd9",
        "date": "2019-07-17T04:55:47"
    }
}
```

Hopefully it is useful.